# How can I create dynamic rule in apache-flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm using flink with Java and I succeeded in defining a static pattern as follow:

```
Pattern<Event, ?> pattern = Pattern.<Event>
            begin("first")
            .where(
                    new SimpleCondition<Event>() {
                        @Override
                            public boolean filter(Event event) {
                            return event.getTemperature() > 50;
                         }
                    }).within(Time.seconds(10L));
```

Is there a way in apache-flink to create patterns in a dynamic way?
I need to define the pattern according to user's input.

Thanks

Comment: Is user input in this case a `DataStream` ? Or just arguments that are passed to a job ?

Comment: user's input is the input that i need in order to build the condition.
for my understanding, data stream will be the event itself

Comment: But how are You going to get the input from the user then ?

Comment: we will get the user's input by a REST call e.g. POST /createRule with JSON that defines the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the "[Dynamic Updates of Application Logic](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/03/24/demo-fraud-detection-2.html)" pattern.

Use BroadcastStream for your rules that you `connect` to the stream.

With the example in the article you could even have dynamic aggregations definitions:

```
// Streams setup
DataStream<Transaction> transactions = [...]
DataStream<Rule> rulesUpdateStream = [...]

BroadcastStream<Rule> rulesStream = rulesUpdateStream.broadcast(RULES_STATE_DESCRIPTOR);

// Processing pipeline setup
 DataStream<Alert> alerts =
     transactions
         .connect(rulesStream)
         .process(new DynamicKeyFunction())
         .keyBy((keyed) -> keyed.getKey())
         .connect(rulesStream)
         .process(new DynamicAlertFunction())
```